# Pyspark - Check column string against list of words and remove

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

PySpark Version 2.4.3
AWS Glue

I have a list of words(patterns):

```
to_remove = ['_test1"','_test2','_test3']
```

and a DF like so:

```
INPUT:
+------+-----------+
| col0 | col1      |
+------|-----------+
| row1 | one_test1"|
| row2 | one_test2 |
+------------------+
```

I would like to check col1 against my list of words and if that word(pattern) is present I want to delete it. Giving me an output like so:

```
OUTPUT:
+------+-----------+
| col0 | col1      |
+------|-----------+
| row1 | one       |
| row2 | one       |
+------------------+
```

The best I could do was the following - However it's only good for one word:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
new_df = old_df.withColumn('clean_text', regexp_replace('col1', '_test1"', ''))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `|` to indicate `or` in a regex:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

to_remove = ['_test1"','_test2','_test3']
new_df = old_df.withColumn(
    'clean_text', 
    F.regexp_replace('col1', '|'.join(to_remove), '')
)

new_df.show()
+----+----------+----------+
|col0|      col1|clean_text|
+----+----------+----------+
|row1|one_test1"|       one|
|row2| one_test2|       one|
+----+----------+----------+
```